# Display Word and excel files in web page from database in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008, ms-word, literals

I have a database where i have saved documents like pdf, word(docx) and excel. I want to display them on web page on view button click. I am able to display pdf file using the below approach.

```
  string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" 
  height=\"600px\">";
  ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/Handler1.ashx? 
id="+id+"&Name="+Name+""), temp);// literal control
```

in Handler1.ashx i have the below

```
 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select pdfdoc from repository;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {      
                            sdr.Read();
                            bytes = (byte[])sdr["BPM_Doc"];
                    }     
                }
                    con.Close();
            }

            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            context.Response.End();
```

How can i use the same approach to display word and excel. My word document has images too.

Comment: Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: Have you *tried* anything? Have you tried changing the `object` tag? Although it's not guaranteed to work even for PDF. `object` doesn't do anything by itself, it's a very old tag that depends on the browser finding a program that can display an object inside the browser. It won't work unless the end user has Excel or Word installed. It *may* work without Acrobat only because several browsers have built-in support for PDF. It may still not work if Word and Excel no longer allow displaying stuff through the `object` tag

Comment: i have tried giving type=\"application/ms-word\. but it dint work. I have both excel and word installed

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly view the Word documents and Excel spreadsheets within your ASP.NET web application. You will have to first render the documents in the form (i.e. HTML or image) that can be displayed on your web page. You can have a look at the following article that shows how to create a universal document viewer application in ASP.NET MVC using **GroupDocs.Viewer for .NET** API.

- [Document Viewer in ASP.NET Core MVC for 140+ File Formats](https://blog.groupdocs.com/2019/11/21/document-viewer-in-asp-net-core-mvc-csharp/)

*Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.*

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **you can't** - at least not the way your going about it even if you have the Office suite installed on your own machine.

PDF documents are handled by most browsers with their own implementation of Adobe's PDF reader - what I suspect your browser is doing, but Microsoft Office documents use a multitude of mimetypes, ranging from `application/ms-word` for the older Word files, to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` for the newer generations of Office, so built-in browser support for even displaying them is either going to be technically unviable, or restricted by license.

Checkout this document viewer to build the reader/viewer into your project directly:

[ASP.NET Document Viewer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Document-Viewer-e7c2a39f) from [GroupDocs](https://products.groupdocs.com/viewer/net)

Note: This is ***not free*** by any means, it's actually quite expensive and I wish anyone luck trying to find one that will be cheap.

Also, don't be content with simply providing your user with the file itself unless you're happy they should have the means to open it.
In my line of work, the end users we deal with don't have Microsoft Office installed on their machines by design (licensing really), so providing information through PDF documents is the only way to go.